# Why do I not have to login to websites when using Edge but I do with Chrome?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I don't usually use Microsoft Edge for browsing unless by accident. Today, I accidentally used it an notice I was already logged into Google Mail. I opened Chrome an noticed I had to sign it to Google Mail. I then rebooted my computer and immediately opened Edge; still didn't have to login. I went to Stack Overflow to ask this question and noticed I was already logged in there as well. I then verified Chrome was asking for authentication. How and why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because you turn on the **Offer to save passwords** and
**Sign in automatically** in Edge (assuming you're using Edge Chromium):

[image]

In Chrome, I think you turn off **Offer to save passwords** and **Auto Sign-in** so that you'll be asked for confirmation every time before signing in to a website:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, That's what it was. I don't remember setting it but I hardly use it.

Answer (score 1):

for me both chrome and edge auto signs in when I open a website, It's probably that you didn't allow chomre to save your stats, look at [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/54490?hl=en)